# android:exported error but already declared in the Manifest Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My Manifest File Code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.nms">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Nurse Call Alerts"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,MissingClass">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:showWhenLocked="true"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:turnScreenOn="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

    <service
        android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="StartupActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.LocatorBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.BootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.LocatorService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    <service
        android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.IsolateHolderService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</application>
```

Comment: `Error: Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value ...` That is not an error. That is documentation. You did not describe a problem or an error in your post. Nor do i see a question.

Comment: after run this project, at bottom of android studio some error comes, add that error in this question , so it is help you.

Comment: Please check again i added few more lines of my console

Comment: This project is a Flutter Project!

Answer (score 1):

Set android:exported = "false"

```
<service android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.IsolateHolderService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service
    android:name="rekab.app.background_locator.LocatorService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

for both services. Thanks